# mysql concat and insert into not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i have a code in stored procedure which adds "PID-" to the id number, so if id number is 1, the result shoulb be PID-1. but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `inserproducts`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `inserproducts`(pid int,pname varchar(50),pdesc varchar(50),psupp varchar(50),pdate date,pquant int)
begin
insert into products(productid,productname,proddescription,supplier,lastpurchasedate,quantityleft)
        values(select concat('PID',pid,pname),pdesc,psupp,pdate,pquant));

select pid=last_insert_id();
end
```

how can i join insert into and concat together? Please help me with this one.

Comment: do you really need the select in there???

Comment: select in what?i have 2 select there u know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
insert into products(productname,proddescription,supplier,lastpurchasedate,quantityleft)
select concat('PID',pid,pname),pdesc,psupp,pdate,pquant
```

You can omit the column `productid` if it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

*I was wondering why you need to execute `select pid=last_insert_id();` when `pid` is an `IN` parameter*.

**UPDATE 1**

```
DROP PROCEDURE `inserproducts`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `inserproducts`
(
   pid int,
   pname varchar(50),
   pdesc varchar(50),
   psupp varchar(50),
   pdate date,
   pquant int
)
begin

    insert into products
          (productname,
           proddescription,
           supplier,
           lastpurchasedate,
           quantityleft)
    select concat('PID',pid,pname), pdesc, psupp, pdate, pquant;

    select last_insert_id();
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: where's the word "values" there? il use select pid=last_insert-id() for my vb6 code. bty, it's not working. lots of errors.

Comment: @HandyManny wht is the error? `INSERT INTO...SELECT` don't have `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: can you provide the whole code like those in my post but with the correct one? I'l just copy&paste because really it has a lot of errors.

Comment: I need to include the "last-insert_id" part because I'm using listview in my vb6. When I want to add another record, I want to increment the last id with "1" so that i have a new id and it will not be duplicated

Comment: i still have problem, when i tried to add new record in listview, only the number(id) is printed out in the id column, "PID" is missing.

Comment: Superb.. concat('PID',pid,pname) working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

just following up... if you specify values you don't need the select - there's probably a slight performance gain by just using values:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `inserproducts`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `inserproducts`
(
    in pid int,
    in pname varchar(50),
    in pdesc varchar(50),
    in psupp varchar(50),
    in pdate date,
    in pquant int
)
begin
    insert into products
        (productname, proddescription, supplier, lastpurchasedate, quantityleft)
    values
        (concat('PID',pid,pname), pdesc, psupp, pdate, pquant );

    select last_insert_id();
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'd leave select alone unless you actually need data from another table...