# SQL Concatenation Not Incrementing

Tags: sql, concatenation

I am trying to insert data into my SQL table and concatenate two columns at the same time.

```
insert into users (cid, username) values (concat('b', id), 'testusername');
```

The ID column is set to auto_increment and when I run the above code it places '1' in the ID column and it places 'testusername' in the username column. This is great. However, the cid column reads 'b0'. I'd like it to say 'b1'.

Furthermore, if I run the statement again, I'd like row 2 to show the value 'b2' in the cid column, but it repeats the value 'b0'. How do I get the cid column to correctly read the incrementing ID column during concatenation?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391600/mysql-concat-and-insert-into-not-working

Comment: Many thanks for the reference, Branimir, but I am still only getting a list of 'B0' values instead of 'B1', 'B2' etc. in my cid column. Do I need to create the full procedure, as shown in the question that you referenced?

Comment: is it necessary that you save "b" as well? could you just save the number?

Comment: No you don't needto create full procedure. Post table structure and select query where are you getting cid.